# ¿Qué es "a caballo" en "papas fritas a caballo"?

Tags: etimología, expresiones, argentina

En Argentina (pero no restringido a la misma), ¿qué es "a caballo" en "papas fritas a caballo"? ¿Y cuál es la etimología?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Según [este foro](http://forum.wordreference.com/threads/a-caballo-gastronom%C3%ADa.791830/?hl=es):

> En Argentina dentro del campo gastronómico llamamos "a caballo" a las comidas que, una vez preparadas, son acompañadas por dos huevos fritos apoyados encima.
>   Unas papas fritas a caballo son papas fritas con dos huevos fritos arriba, un bife a caballo viene también con dos huevos arriba, etc. También decimos "a medio caballo" para referirnos a un sólo huevo frito en vez de dos.

La etimología en principio parece clara: los huevos están como montados a caballo sobre lo que sea que esté debajo.

Comment: En Colombia «a Caballo» significa con huevo frito encima. El número de huevos es opcional pero generalmente es uno solo por lo que no existe el término «a medio caballo» aunque debería ya que me parece muy práctico en lugar de tener que decir «pero un solo huevo por favor»

Comment: La primera referencia que se conoce es de **1882**. El cronista Eugenio Cambaceres [describe](http://old.clarin.com.ar/pbda/novela/potpourri/potpourri_07.html) a los comensales de una "fonda" en la Estación Altamirano, en la pampa de Argentina, de la siguiente forma:

Comment: _"...Uniformemente y sin excepción, usan los codos sobre la mesa, comen con el cuchillo, cortan con él el pan y se lo meten a la boca sin soltar por eso de la mano el filoso instrumento, no necesitan servilleta porque echan mano del referido mantel cuyos bordes son un mosaico de manchas de grasa y yema de huevo, interpelan a gritos al mozo pidiéndole un **bife con dos a caballo**, su plato favorito, y aderezan su comida con una ensalada de ajos que a cada paso intercalan en su conversación con los otros comensales."_

Comment: Siempre me pareció la explicación más lógica, pero también hay [otra](http://www.planetajoy.com/?page=ampliada&id=1737) que dice que el hombre que proveía de papas y huevos a la mujer que inventó las papas fritas a caballo era tan pobre que, en vez de tener carro, hacía el reparto a caballo, y por eso a todo lo que llevaba huevos encima se le empezó a decir "a caballo". Si bien ya conocía esa explicación, no encontré fuentes más confiables que la que cito.

Comment: No tenía ni idea de todo esto, en España he visto muchas veces hamburguesas con el nombre "a caballo", ahora que sé esto supongo que es la que lleva huevo.

Comment: Muy buena respuesta.  Quedaría mejor aún con una foto....

Comment: En Chile a esto lo llamamos "a lo pobre". Por ejemplo, el Bistec a lo pobre consiste en un plato con un bistec con papas fritas, cebolla frita y encima un par de huevos fritos. [Imagen de ejemplo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lDunE.png).